# Processing large grids with Dask results in MemoryError

Tags: geospatial, dask, amazon-emr, dask-distributed, rasterio

I have three GeoTIFFs, each roughly 500 MB in size on AWS' S3, which I am trying to process on an EMR cluster using Dask, but I obtain a MemoryError after the processing the first tiff.

After reading the GeoTIFF using `xarray.open_rasterio()`, I convert the grid values to boolean then multiply the array by a floating point value. This workflow has executed successfully on three GeoTIFFs 50 MBs in size. Additionally, I have tried using chunking when reading with xarray, but have obtained the same results.

Is there a size limitation with Dask or another possible issue I could be running into?

Comment: Don't know about the EMR specifications, but on a normal machine this file size and operation should not be a problem whatsoever, normal or chunked. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a size limitation with Dask or another possible issue I could be running into?

Dask itself does not artificially impose any size limitations.  It is just a normal Python process.  I recommend thinking about normal Python or hardware issues.  My first guess would be that you're using very small VMs, but that's just a guess.  Good luck!